# How to get arrayList values inside a javascript to html <c: forEach>

Tags: javascript, java, arraylist

I have an arraList inside a `javascript`.I want to get that arrayList to iterate inside `html` `<c:forEach>`.How can I do this. I can get this arrayList to a `<h:outputText>` but I want to iterate the list.
My `javascript` arraList is like this

```
<script>    
    topCategory = new Array();
    topCategory.push("one");
    topCategory.push("two");
    topCategory.push("threee");
    topCategory.push("four");
</script>
```

I need to iterate this `topCategory` inside a `html` `<c:forEach>`

for ex:

```
<script>    
topCategory = new Array();
topCategory.push("one");
topCategory.push("two");
topCategory.push("threee");
topCategory.push("four");
```

then this list should be iterated inside a

```
<table width="100%">          
  <tr>
   <td rowspan="2" width="20%">
     <c:forEach items="#{topCategory}" var="cat">
       <p:commandButton value="#{cat}"/>
              </c:forEach>   
    </td>
  </tr>
```

Comment: how is this related to java?

Comment: If you want a `<c:forEach>`, write one.

Comment: @Jaiprakash `<c:forEach>` is from the *JSP* standard tag library, used to iterate *Java* arrays, collections, etc.

Comment: @Andreas To write a   `<c:forEach>`  I need to pass that arrayList to `html`.I want to know how to do that.I do not want to add a  `<c:forEach>` inside the javascript. I need to pass the topCategory arrayList ïnside `html` like ` <c:forEach item="topCategory " ..`

Comment: @chinthi may be you can use knockoutjs for iterating in html

Comment: @ManojKrishna can you tell me how to do it or link of a tutorial or example for that

Comment: @chinthi you can try my answer if it works for you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know this is a late reply . Hope this will help you. In my understand you need to iterate a array from `javascript` and in side the html you need to show that as button . So you can use `document.createElement()` and `appendChild` .Here is the sample ,

```
function getButtonSet(topCategory){
    $('#renderList').empty();
    (function(){
         var t, tt;                        
         category.forEach(renderProductList);
         function renderProductList(element, index, arr) {
            var inputElement = document.createElement("input");                                    
            inputElement.setAttribute("type", "button");
            inputElement.setAttribute("value", element);
            inputElement.setAttribute("name", element);
            var foo = document.getElementById("renderList");
            foo.appendChild(inputElement);
            t = document.createTextNode(element);
          }
     }
}
```

Inside you `<td></td>` replace the `<c:forEach></c:forEach>` with `<div id="renderList" ></div>`

Comment: thaks for the reply I tried with it and It solved the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Your **JSP** file should just have a `<c:forEach>` loop where you want to iterate.

```
<script>
topCategory = new Array();
<c:forEach var="val" items="${list}">
topCategory.push("${val}");
</c:forEach>
</script>
```

This will generate the JavaScript code you showed in the generated HTML, from the `ArrayList` provided by your *Java* action handler, so you end up with a *JavaScript array* in the browser.

*Warning:* This only works for simple text values, like you show. The text should be JavaScript encoded if it can contain special characters.

Comment: Thanks but I need iterate the topCategory outside the javascript like bellow.`<script>    
    topCategory = new Array();
    topCategory.push("one");
    topCategory.push("two");
    topCategory.push("threee");
    topCategory.push("four");
</script> `

Comment: I'm sorry, you're confusing things. `<c:forEach>` is a JSP JSTL tag, and runs on the *server* when it is building the HTML source dynamically. `<script>` and the code inside it, is executed by the browser *on the client*, after the HTML has been generated on the server. Keep clear in your mind what is executing where and when. In *Java* and the *JSP*, you can use an `ArrayList`. In *JavaScript*, you are using an `Array`. Totally different thing. Java != JavaScript. ArrayList != Array.

Comment: Thanks I edited my question can you see it again.I need a way to do this task.

Comment: As I said, keep clear in your mind what is executing where. The script code is running **client-side**, and it is creating a JavaScript *Array*, not an arraList, whatever that is. `<c:forEach>` and `<p:commandButton>` are *JSP tags*, which is running **server-side**, and *cannot see the client-side array*.

Answer (score 0):

If you really want to create your list and iterate on during the HTML generation server side, use:
`<c:set var="array" value="${["one","two"]}">`

See : [Creating Array using JSTL or EL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14454769/creating-array-using-jstl-or-el)

Answer (score 0):

```js
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js'> </script>
<script>


function AppViewModel()
{

 topCategory = ko.observableArray([]);
    topCategory.push("one");
    topCategory.push("two");
    topCategory.push("threee");
    topCategory.push("four");
}


    
    
ko.applyBindings(AppViewModel);




</script>
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<title>Title of the document</title>
<script type='text/javascript' src='http://ajax.aspnetcdn.com/ajax/knockout/knockout-3.3.0.js'></script>

</head>

<body>
The content of the document......
<br>
<ul data-bind="foreach: topCategory">
    <li>
         <b data-bind="text: $data"></b>
    </li>
</ul>
```

you can try this